# Changing the restrictions from the last table th

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have the following table

```
<table>
  <TableHeader className="execution-head"/>
    <tbody>
      <tr className={this.props.className} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <th>{this.props.execution_id}</th>
        <th>{this.props.launch_time}</th>
        // more th's here
      </tr>
      <tr className={this.props.className} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <th>{this.props.execution_id}</th>
        <th>{this.props.launch_time}</th>
        // more th's here
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>+</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**output:**

```
<table data-reactid=".1">
 <thead data-reactid=".1.0">
  <tr class="execution-head" data-reactid=".1.0.0">
     <th data-reactid=".1.0.0.0">ID</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.0.0.1">Launch Time</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.0.0.5">Execution Time</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody data-reactid=".1.1">
  <tr class="execution-row" data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4x324">
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4x324.0">4x324</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4x324.1">11.11.15 13:30</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4x324.5">2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="execution-row" data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4823748">
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4823748.0">4823748</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4823748.1">13.11.15 13:30:25</th>
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.0:$4823748.5">34</th>
  <tr class="table-plus" data-reactid=".1.1.1">
     <th data-reactid=".1.1.1.0">+</th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the last tr element take the whole width of the table, but from everything that I've tried it always comes out wrong.

P.S this is written with react if you are wondering

Comment: instead of posting the react code. Can you just post what is coming out as end product i.e. html code

Comment: Edited and added whats coming out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count the number of `th`s in a variable, lets say `col_cnt`
Then in the last `tr` you can write this:

```
<tr>
 <th colspan="{col_cnt}">+</th>
</tr>
```